# Page reload after pjax

Tags: javascript, html, pjax

everybody!
I try to use jquery-pjax 
I have html code with fragments:

```
<li id="left_menu_item"><a href="myurl">Caption</a></li>
...
<div class="right-block" id="content">
</div>
```

and js-code

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#content');

$(document).on('pjax:send', function() {
    console.log('pjax:send');
});
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
    console.log('pjax:complete');
});
$(document).on('pjax:success', function() {
    console.log('pjax:success');
});
$(document).on('pjax:error', function() {
    console.log('pjax:error');
});
$(document).on('pjax:timeout', function() {
    console.log('pjax:timeout');
});
```

And I receive 'pjax:error' and 'pjax:timeout' messages. Ok. I added

```
$.pjax.defaults.timeout = false;
```

Now in Javascript console all right: 'pjax:send' and 'pjax:complete'. But page reload after this! Why?

Comment: Browsers Chrome 24.0 & Firefox 17.0

Comment: In the browser's developer tools, you should be able to configure the console to persist even after the reload. Have you done that? And when you do, can you tell if the error callback is being fired?

Comment: Yes, i did it earlier. There is no messages about error.

`pjax:send myscript.js:10
pjax:complete myscript.js:13
pjax:send myscript.js:10
pjax:complete myscript.js:13`

That's all.

Comment: Do you need to use the `fragment` option?

Comment: @SeanHogan I don't use it now.

Comment: Can you persist the `Net` tab in the console and post the HTTP headers and response-text of AJAX'ed pages?

Comment: @SeanHogan I make demo and upload on my website http://indapublic.ru/pjax/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When `jquery-pjax` is used to progressively enhance a static HTML site you must use the `fragment` option.

In your case the code would be something like:

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#content', { fragment: '#content' });
```

You should also ensure that your HTML is valid - `jquery-pjax` parsing of HTML isn't exactly like the browser

`jquery-pjax` also has a bug where text-nodes that are direct children of the fragment are stripped. Make sure your content is wrapped in elements, e.g.

```
<div id="content">
  <p>Page 1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it working correctly now. Try to use this on working project. Thank you very much.
One question: Are there any jquery-pjax alternatives?

Comment: Page partial reload. What is the best solution for this? I use Google search, and I found jquery-pjax only

Comment: I think the current alternatives are yui-pjax, djax, htmldecor.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can I ask one more question?
If i have two divs, "breadcrumbs" and "content", and I want to change them separately (because div "filters" is exists between them) - what I must to do? I try to make two $.pjax.click, first with {push: false}. But it not working - while I press "Back" button, only "content" is changing, "breadcrumbs" remain the same.

Comment: OK. Last answer. Only call pjax for content. Hook onto pjax:success and pjax:popstate events to manage breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#content', { push: false, replaceRedirect: false });
```